# Solve log equation $\frac{3}{log_2(10)}-log(x-9)=log(44)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to solve $\frac{3}{log_2(10)}-log(x-9)=log(44)$.

The textbook solution provided is $x=\frac{101}{11}$ but I am unable to arrive at a solution.

Here's as far as I was able to get:

$$\frac{3}{log_2(10)}-log(x-9)=log(44)$$

I want to convert the denominator $log_2$ into the same base (10) as the others:
$$log_2(10)=\frac{log(10)}{log(2)}$$

Now swapping this in I have:

$$\frac{3}{(\frac{log(10)}{log(2)})}-log(x-9)=log(44)$$

Which I think I can rewrite as:

$$\frac{3}{log(\frac{10}{2})}-log(x-9)=log(44)$$

Which can be simplified to:

$$\frac{3}{log(5)}-log(x-9)=log(44)$$

This is as far as I got. I don't know where to go next or if I'm on the right track. The 3 in the numerator is what's stumping me, I don't know how to handle it.

How can I solve this equation to arrive at $x=\frac{101}{11}$?

More granular baby steps much appreciated.

[EDIT]
From a commenter, I'm working through an open online textbook, exercise number 63 at the bottom of [this](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry@27.1/pages/6-6-exponential-and-logarithmic-equations) page. The corresponding solution for chapter 66, exercise 63 is on [this](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/chapter-6) page.

Comment: Are you sure you copy the problem correctly? What is the base for $\log(44)$? $e$ or $10$?

Comment: Hi @mrsamy I have added links to the online textbook pages above

Comment: Thanks for the reference. That makes sense. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in your exercise $\log$ means $\log_{10}$. So you have $\log(10)=1$.

Now,

\begin{align}
\frac{3}{\log_2(10)}-\log(x-9)&=\log(44)\\
\log(x-9)&=\frac{3}{\log_2(10)}-\log(44)&\textrm{(put the unknown to one side)}\\
\log(x-9)&=\frac{3\log(2)}{\log(10)}-\log(44)&(\log_2(10)=\frac{\log(10)}{\log(2)})\\
\log(x-9)&=3\log(2)-\log(44)\\
\log(x-9)&=\log\frac{2^3}{44}\\
x-9&=\frac{8}{44}\\
x&=\frac{101}{11}
\end{align}

---

Notes.

In general,
$$
\log \frac{b}{a}\ne \frac{\log b}{\log a}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\log$ means $\log_{10}$ then your mistake is in this step
$$\frac{3}{(\frac{\log(10)}{\log(2)})} = \frac{3}{(\log(10/2)}$$

You should have $\log_{10}-\log{2}$.

By properties of $\log$

$$\log \left( \frac{a}{b}\right) = \log a - \log b$$

Answer (score 0):

$\log(10)/\log2=1/\log2$.  Note $\log(10/2)=\log10-\log2$

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake $\frac3{\log_2 10 } \ne \frac{3}{\log_{10} 5}$

Using, $\boxed{\log_b(a) = \frac{1}{\log_a(b)}}$

$\frac3{\log_2 10 } = 3\log_{10} 2 = \log_{10}8$

From here, $ \log_{10}(x-9) = \log_{10}(\frac2{11})$ or $x = \frac{101}{11}$

Answer (score 0):

Expressing everything using natural logarithms, we see that

$\frac{3}{log_2(10)}-log(x-9)=log(44)$

$\frac{3}{log_2(10)}-log_{10}(x-9)=log_{10}(44)$

is equal to

$3\frac{ln (2)}{ln (10)}-\frac{ln(x-9)}{ln (10)}=\frac{ln (44)}{ln (10)}$

$ln(\frac{8}{x-9})=ln (44)$

i.e.

$x=\frac{101}{11}$.